# How can I use IF statements with string user inputs?

Tags: c++, string

I'm a c++ newbie and have spent half a day googling this. Most posts seem vague or complex. And I have a feeling that there's a simpler way to do this. Any help is appreciated.
A simple program that calculates tax based on the state entered by user:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your order amount: ";
    int amount{};
    std::cin >> amount;

    std::cout << "Which state do you reside in? ";
    std::string state{};
    std::cin >> state;

    if (state == "WI") //THIS IS SIMILAR TO HOW I WOULD DO IT IN PYTHON | C++ doesn't work this way
        std::cout << "Your tax is 5.0$" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Your total is " << amount + 5.0;

    else
        std::cout << "Your tax is 0.0$" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Your total is " << amount;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is pretty nice for a newby. A lot of info can be found on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: yes c++ works this way. You can compare a std::string to another string with the operator == . You however need parentheses around all the things that are in the if statement. In C++ you need to use {} instead of indentation to indicate scope.

Comment: This has nothing to do with strings, but with proper C++ grammar. C++ is not Python, and indentation is utterly meaningless in C++. You need to use braces. See your C++ book for more information.

Comment: @constraintAutomaton welcome to modern C++... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Comment: Typo: missing `{ ...  }`  after the `if` and `else`, to group the statements

Comment: Since you are coming from Python, I would recommend frequent reformatting in your IDE to indent based on the logic until you get used to C++ style/structure differences.

Comment: Adding braces{ } under the if and else statements solved it. Thank you for the immediate responses.

Comment: BTW, while the C++ compiler cares not one whit for how much whitespace you use or how you indent your code, people do. And code isn't for computers. It's for people. Otherwise, you'd just be writing out the numbers for the CPU instructions you want to execute. So, use proper indentation even if you don't have to. The indentation habits Python gave you will serve you well here, and they're precisely why Python made whitespace and indentation matter, to force people to indent their code properly by making the interpreter care as much about it as the people reading the code.

Comment: @PraveenGunasekaran You can also replace the first semicolon after the if and else with comma and it'll also work.

Comment: @Omnifarious thank you for clarifying that. I was aware that C++ didn't have any rules on indentation. I simply carried over the indentation style from python to make it readable, as you said.

Comment: @AnArrayofFunctions I'm not sure what you mean. Both the if and else statements don't have a semicolon at the end. If you mean the conditional executions, I tried it and am getting an error. Even if it did compile, it seems arbitrary. If you could clarify what you meant and maybe shed light on it might be useful in certain situations, that would be great. Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: @PraveenGunasekaran I mean after the first cout after the if and else statement. I mean `std::cout << "Your tax is 5.0$" << std::endl,` instead of `std::cout << "Your tax is 5.0$" << std::endl;` and `std::cout << "Your tax is 0.0$" << std::endl,` in place of `std::cout << "Your tax is 0.0$" << std::endl;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the addition of `{` and `}` to group the statements after the if and else

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your order amount: ";
    int amount{};
    std::cin >> amount;

    std::cout << "Which state do you reside in? ";
    std::string state{};
    std::cin >> state;

    if (state == "WI")
    {
        std::cout << "Your tax is 5.0$" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Your total is " << amount + 5.0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Your tax is 0.0$" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Your total is " << amount;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After an `if (condition)` or `else` the language only allows a single statement.  The braces `{` and `}` enclose a sequence of statements into a Compound Statement.

For possibly clearer language see **Compound statements** here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements

Comment: Maybe an explanation of the "compound statement" would be good here?